# Remove control characters from UNIX Domain Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, unix

i have a problem with docker exec command output, when i try to run (with got)

```js
 const output = await client.runCommand([
      "cat -v ./tmp/schema.json"
  ]);
```

Where `runCommand` return a stream with docker socket of exec command

```js
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let chunks = [];

      stream.on("data", (chunk) => { 
        let output = chunk.toString();
        chunks.push(output);
      });

      stream.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
      stream.on("end", () => resolve(chunks.join("")));
    });
```

but when i parse with json parse the result of this promise i receive this  control characters

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85U0I.png)

is possible to remove this control characters from the chunks?

Answer (score 0):

you can check and replace if the chunk contains any UNIX control character

```
chunk.replaceAll(/[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/g, "")
```

Comment: i try to replace with this regex but in the code i receive a lot of this special charter � and ?

Comment: let's try something different, `Buffer.from(chunk, 'utf-8').toString();`

Comment: i try to do this, but i receive � the same charters